# How to update Mongo DB document with complex structure

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongoDB document with the following structure

```
{
  "id": 9595511812,
  "Feeds": [
    {
      "department": "mseb",
      "consumer_number": 1234567890,
      "due_date": "2016-11-11",
      "due_amount": 400,
      "balance_amount": 0,
      "unitsConsumed": 40,
      "freezeDate": "2016-11-11",
      "lastPaidDate": "2016-11-11",
      "billNumber": "9877",
      "id": "1",
      "paid": false
    },
    {
      "department": "mseb",
      "consumer_number": 1234567890,
      "due_date": "2016-11-21",
      "due_amount": 400,
      "balance_amount": 0,
      "unitsConsumed": 40,
      "freezeDate": "2016-11-21",
      "lastPaidDate": "2016-11-21",
      "billNumber": "9877",
      **"id": "2",**
      "paid": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update paid == true for Feed with id=2 (** marked field above). How can I do that in using mongo java client?

I have tried

```
 DB db = DBConnection.getDatabaseConnection();
        DBCollection table = db.getCollection("customer");
        BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
        newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("Feeds.paid", "true"));

        BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("id", "9595511812");

        table.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Feeds` is an array, and you're updating the 2nd element, so the `set` would end with:

```
.append("Feeds.1.paid", "true"));
```

instead of:

```
.append("Feeds.paid", "true"));
```

Comment: My document is   {
 "_id": 9595511812,
 "password": "password@123",
 "name": "Akanksha Jain",
 "address": "Katraj, Pune",
 "email": "akanksha_jain@psl.com",
 "eCivilBody": [{
  "id" : 1,
  "department": "mseb",
  "consumer_number": 1234567890,
  "due_amount": 400,
  "balance_amount": "0",
  "freezeDate": "2016-11-11",
  "unitsConsumed": 40,
  "due_date": "2016-11-11",
  "lastPaidDate": "2016-11-11",
  "billNumber": "9877",
  "paid": "false"
 }]
}

Comment: and my code snippet is DB db = DBConnection.getDatabaseConnection();
         DBCollection table = db.getCollection("customer");
         BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
         newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("eCivilBody.1.paid", "true"));

         BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("id", "9923052628");

         table.update(searchQuery, newDocument);

Comment: Yes ...? That's another case ? The case in the question is working but not this one ...?

Comment: The `id` is not matching (9595511812 vs 9923052628) in the code you pasted